# How to print data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, printing

I am supposed to create webpage with a list of literature, where admin will maintain the list and users will be able to choose the books and print a list. I already have the web app done, but I have no idea, how to print it. Definetly some button, which will print just the data in a list. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [print stylesheet](http://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-customized-print-stylesheet-in-minutes/) so when a user hits 'print' from their browser, you are able to customize what appears in the final printout.

You can do this by using CSS to hide headers, menu's or whatever else you don't want your user to print.